# Passing Child.class as argument

Tags: java, class

I have a method that should receives a `Class<A>`, something like:

```
protected void method(final Class<A> clazz) {
}
```

Then when I try to call like `method(A.class)` it do works, but if I try `method(B.class)`, where `B` is child of `A`, I get the message "incompatible types".

The solution is change to `Class<B>`, but I have another childs that I like to pass as argument to this `method()`, like `C.class`.

Comment: Related: [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265)

Answer (score 8):

One solution would be to use a bounded wildcard when defining the parameter:

```
protected void method(final Class<? extends A> clazz) {
    // Code here...
}
```

With this, you are allowed to pass `A`'s class directly or any class that extends from `A`.

Or as Pavlo suggested:

```
protected <T extends A> void method(final Class<T> clazz) {
    // Code here...
}
```

Both will work, but it would help to know what you plan to do with `clazz` so we can select one over the other.

Comment: I'll suggest using `protected <T extends Number> void method(final Class<T> clazz)` will be event better because it allows you to avoid wildcard mess when you will try to call methods on your `clazz`.

Comment: @PavloViazovskyy what generics mess are you referring to? All you can invoke on a `Class<? extends A>` are producer methods; and that's simply (e.g.) `A instance = clazz.getInstance();`.

Comment: @AndyTurner. Yes, you're right. That's my mistake. Since `Class` doesn't have consumer methods (which take `T` as parameter), it's enough to use wildcard version of the method as originally suggested by _Jacob_.